# PHP Cron jobs return "-: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: ELF load command past end of file"

Tags: php, linux, cron, scheduled-tasks

I would like to run a few PHP cron jobs on my server.
Scheduler notification is set and the result would be sent to my email.

However, they fail to run, and I keep receiving emails with following contents:

```
-: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: ELF load command past end of file
```

Environment:

> CentOS Linux 7.0.1406 (Core)
>   with Plesk

Cron job commands that I have tried in Plesk, but same result:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/cron/file.php
php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/cron/file.php
```

Checked that the PHP file runs normally without error via HTTP request.
But I would like to **use php instead of wget**

The cron job command runs without error via SSH to the server.

```
whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/lib64/php /etc/php.d /etc/php.ini /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz

whereis libc.so.6
libc.so: /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 /usr/lib64/libc.so
```

It seems the library is corrupted.
May I know how to reinstall or overwrite the corrupted library?
Not having much knowledge on server management, please suggest me ways to solve the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Oh, even I put `which php` as cron job command, it returns `-: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: ELF load command past end of file`

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
yum resinstall glibc
```